# Knockout : I have to perform an action after two observable array get populated

Tags: knockout.js

I am new to knockout.In my viewmodel I have perform an action only when two observable arrays get populated from database. How can I achieve this?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The easiest way is to define `computed` observable that checks length of every array and returns `true` if both lengths are not zeroes.

```
self.bothPopulated = ko.computed(function(){
    return self.array1().length > 0 && self.array2().length > 0;
});
```

Then just subscribe on it with appropriate action:

```
self.bothPopulated.subscribe(function(val){
    if (val) alert('both populated');
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/Zk6Lc/